# VerifyCommitted - Transaction has not been committed error on plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am writing a plugin for Dynamics 2017 on premise using C#.  The plugin is supposed to run synchronously post operation on the win of an opportunity.  When I mark an opportunity as won, I receive the following error:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">VerifyCommitted - Transaction has not been committed</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <OrganizationServiceFault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" 
                    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <ActivityId>11be55c4-321a-4b84-b9b7-f2451579bc67</ActivityId>
                    <ErrorCode>-2147220910</ErrorCode>
                    <ErrorDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
                    <Message>VerifyCommitted - Transaction has not been committed</Message>
                    <Timestamp>2018-07-05T18:37:53.9996395Z</Timestamp>
                    <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
                    <ExceptionSource i:nil="true"/>
                    <InnerFault i:nil="true"/>
                    <OriginalException i:nil="true"/>
                    <TraceText i:nil="true"/>
                </OrganizationServiceFault>
            </detail>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I've tried profiling the plugin so I can debug what is happening here, but it doesn't appear that the plugin is successfully profiling the action.  Why am I receiving this error and why is my plugin not profiling correctly?

```
    private void ExecutePostOpportunityWin(LocalPluginContext localContext)
    {
        if (localContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("localContext");
        }

        try
        {
            IPluginExecutionContext context = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;
            Entity wonOpportunityEntity = context.InputParameters.Contains("OpportunityClose") ?
                (Entity)context.InputParameters["OpportunityClose"] :
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Unable to load OpportunityClose Input Parameter. Please try again in a few minutes.  If the problem persists please contact IT Support.");

            EntityReference wonOpportunityReference = wonOpportunityEntity.Attributes.Contains("opportunityid") ?
                (EntityReference)wonOpportunityEntity.Attributes["opportunityid"] :
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Unable to load opportunityid. Please try again in a few minutes.  If the problem persists please contact IT Support.");

            IOrganizationService service = localContext.OrganizationService;

            if (wonOpportunityReference != null)
            {
                Opportunity wonOpportunity = (Opportunity)service.Retrieve(
                        "opportunity",
                        new Guid(wonOpportunityReference.Id.ToString()),
                        new ColumnSet(new String[] {
                        "customerid",
                        "ownerid",
                        "ccseq_salesleadid",
                        "description",
                        "ccseq_newcontract",
                        "ccseq_newclient",
                        "ccseq_clientid",
                        "ccseq_contractid",
                        "name"
                        })
                    );


                if (wonOpportunity != null)
                {
                    Boolean isNewClient = wonOpportunity.NewClient == true;
                    Boolean isNewContract = wonOpportunity.NewContract == true;

                    if (isNewClient && isNewContract)
                    {
                        Client newClient = CreateClient(wonOpportunity, service);
                        Contract newContract = CreateContract(wonOpportunity, newClient, service);
                        AssociateOpportunityToContract(wonOpportunity.Id, newContract.Id, service);
                        wonOpportunity.Client = newClient;
                        wonOpportunity.Contract = newContract;
                        wonOpportunity.Save(service);
                    }
                    else if (isNewClient && !isNewContract)
                    {
                        Client newClient = CreateClient(wonOpportunity, service);
                        AssociateOpportunityToContract(wonOpportunity.Id, wonOpportunity.Contract.Id, service);
                        wonOpportunity.Client = newClient;
                        wonOpportunity.Save(service);
                    }
                    else if (!isNewClient && isNewContract)
                    {
                        Entity entity = service.Retrieve(
                            "ccseq_client",
                            wonOpportunity.Client.Id,
                            new ColumnSet(new String[] { "ccseq_clientid", "ccseq_masterclientid" })
                        );

                        Client newClient = (Client)entity;

                        if (newClient.MasterClient != null)
                        {
                            entity = service.Retrieve(
                                "ccseq_client",
                                newClient.Id,
                                new ColumnSet(new String[] { "ccseq_clientid", "ccseq_masterclientid" })
                            );

                            newClient = (Client)entity;
                        }

                        Contract newContract = CreateContract(wonOpportunity, newClient, service);
                        AssociateOpportunityToContract(wonOpportunity.Id, newContract.Id, service);
                        wonOpportunity.Contract = newContract;
                        wonOpportunity.Save(service);
                    }
                    else if (!isNewClient && !isNewContract)
                    {
                        AssociateOpportunityToContract(wonOpportunity.Id, wonOpportunity.Contract.Id, service);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Unable to process Client and Contract Information. Please try again in a few minutes.  If the problem persists please contact IT Support.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Unable to load Opportunity. Please try again in a few minutes.  If the problem persists please contact IT Support.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Unable to load Opportunity. Please try again in a few minutes.  If the problem persists please contact IT Support.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(e.Message);
        }
    }

    private void AssociateOpportunityToContract(Guid opportunityID, Guid contractID, IOrganizationService service)
    {
        service.Associate(
            "ccseq_contract",
            contractID,
            new Relationship("ccseq_ccseq_contract_opportunity_ContractID"),
            new EntityReferenceCollection(
                new EntityReference[] { new EntityReference("opportunity", opportunityID) }
            )
        );
    }

    private Contract CreateContract(Opportunity opportunity, Client clientGroup, IOrganizationService service)
    {
        Contract newContract = new Contract();
        newContract.ApprovingPartner = opportunity.SalesLead;
        newContract.Preparer = opportunity.SalesLead;
        newContract.Description = opportunity.Topic;
        newContract.Executed = false;
        newContract.ContractStatus = Contract.eContractStatus.Draft;
        newContract.ClientGroup = clientGroup;
        newContract.Id = newContract.Save(service);

        ContractLine newContractLine = new ContractLine();
        newContractLine.Contract = newContract;
        newContractLine.Id = newContractLine.Save(service);

        ContractRevenue newContractRevenue = new ContractRevenue();
        newContractRevenue.Contract = newContract;
        newContractRevenue.Id = newContractRevenue.Save(service);

        ContractRevenueByContractLine newContractRevenueByContractLine = new ContractRevenueByContractLine();
        newContractRevenueByContractLine.ContractLine = newContractLine;
        newContractRevenueByContractLine.ContractRevenue = newContractRevenue;
        newContractRevenueByContractLine.Id = newContractRevenueByContractLine.Save(service);

        ContractJob newContractJob = new ContractJob();
        newContractJob.ContractLine = newContractLine;
        newContractJob.Id = newContractJob.Save(service);

        return newContract;
    }

    private Client CreateClient(Opportunity opportunity, IOrganizationService service)
    {
        Client newClient = new Client();
        newClient.Name = opportunity.AssociationOrContact.Name;
        newClient.Originator = opportunity.Originator;
        newClient.Preparer = opportunity.SalesLead;
        newClient.ClientPartner = opportunity.SalesLead;
        newClient.ClientStatus = Client.eClientStatus.Draft;

        if (opportunity.AssociationOrContact != null)
        {
            if (opportunity.AssociationOrContact.LogicalName == "account")
            {
                Association association = null;

                association = (Association)service.Retrieve(
                    "account",
                    opportunity.AssociationOrContact.Id,
                    new ColumnSet(new String[]
                    {
                        "ownershipcode",
                        "industrycode",
                        "ccseq_fiscalyearendmonth",
                        "ccseq_naicscode",
                        "address1_line1",
                        "address1_line2",
                        "address1_line3",
                        "address1_city",
                        "address1_stateorprovince",
                        "address1_postalcode",
                        "address1_country"
                    })
                );


                if (association != null)
                {
                    newClient.Association = association;
                    newClient.FiscalYearEndMonth = association.FiscalYearEndMonth != null ? (Client.eMonthOfYear)association.FiscalYearEndMonth : (Client.eMonthOfYear?)null;
                    //client.ClientType = (Client.eClientType)association.EntityType;   // These two option sets are different
                    newClient.SameAsClientAddress = true;
                    newClient.Address1 = association.Address1_Street1;
                    newClient.Address2 = association.Address1_Street2;
                    newClient.Address3 = association.Address1_Street3;
                    newClient.City = association.Address1_City;
                    newClient.State = association.Address1_State_Province;
                    newClient.Zip = association.Address1_ZIP_PostalCode != null ? Convert.ToInt32(association.Address1_ZIP_PostalCode) : (int?)null;
                    newClient.Country = association.Address1_County;
                    newClient.BillingAddress1 = association.Address1_Street1;
                    newClient.BillingAddress2 = association.Address1_Street2;
                    newClient.BillingAddress3 = association.Address1_Street3;
                    newClient.BillingCity = association.Address1_City;
                    newClient.BillingState = association.Address1_State_Province;
                    newClient.BillingZip = association.Address1_ZIP_PostalCode != null ? Convert.ToInt32(association.Address1_ZIP_PostalCode) : (int?)null;
                    newClient.BillingCountry = association.Address1_County;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Contact contact = (Contact)service.Retrieve(
                    "contact",
                    opportunity.AssociationOrContact.Id,
                    new ColumnSet(new String[]
                    {
                        "firstname",
                        "lastname",
                        "emailaddress1"
                    })
                );

                if (contact != null)
                {
                    newClient.Name = contact.LastName + " Household";
                    newClient.BillingContactName = contact.FirstName + " " + contact.LastName;
                    newClient.BillingContactEmail = contact.PrimaryEmail;
                    // Address Information doesn't quite line up
                }
            }
        }

        newClient.Id = newClient.Save(service);
        return newClient;
    }
```

#### Plugin Configuration

[image: Win of Opportunity Configuration]

Comment: For which stage and mode is your plugin registered?

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen This is a synchronous plugin post operation

Comment: On the update of the Opportunity entity? I think the issue is that you are trying to update the Opportunity record which is locked by the system because of the opportunitywon operation.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen on the win of an opportunity, but probably the same thing.  I'll try removing the opportunity update and see what happens.

Comment: So what did you find out?

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen I believe you were correct on why I was receiving this error.  I ended up making this a Pre-Operation plugin and set the correct values in the target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @HenkvanBoeijen said in the comments on this question the issue was that I was trying to update the opportunity record that had been locked by the system.  When I made this plugin a pre-operation plugin and set the values I needed in the target the error went away.